# RxJava: Understanding difference between simple async operation

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava and encountered a seemingly trivial issue that I'm sure is just my misunderstanding about how RxJava works. I have two code blocks below that demonstrate a simple `Observable` and `Consumer` pair where the `Observable` emits a counting stream of integers from 1 to 4 with a one second delay between each.

**Snippet A** - Causes UI freeze

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.create(e -> {
    e.onNext(1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(3);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(4);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onComplete();
});
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
observable.subscribe(i -> Log.e(TAG, "onNext: " + i));
```

**Snippet B** - Behaves correctly

```
Observable.create(e -> {
    e.onNext(1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(3);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(4);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onComplete();
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(i -> Log.e(TAG, "onNext: " + i));
```

The issue I don't understand is why does Snippet A freeze my UI but Snippet B works just as expected and runs in the background. This code runs from an `onClick` in a `Button` and I can tell Snippet A causes the UI to freeze because the ripple animation stops while Snippet B runs perfectly fine.

**Question:** What is the difference between creating an instance/pointer of `Observable` and using the builder paradigm to initialize the `Observable`? Why do the two code snippets above differ in practice?

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand why people down vote, is there not a clear question or issue I'm asking about with concise code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the concept called **Chaining of Operators**. Every operator will return an observable which will have its effect, you need to subscribe to the new observable returned in previous step to see the effects

`SnippetA` will become

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.create(e -> {
    e.onNext(1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(3);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onNext(4);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    e.onComplete();
});
Observable ioSubscription = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
Observable mainThreadObservable = ioSubscription.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
mainThreadObservable.subscribe(i -> Log.e(TAG, "onNext: " + i));
```

**Chaining Operators**

Most operators operate on an Observable and return an Observable. This allows you to apply these operators one after the other, in a chain. Each operator in the chain modifies the Observable that results from the operation of the previous operator.

There are other patterns, like the Builder Pattern, in which a variety of methods of a particular class operate on an item of that same class by modifying that object through the operation of the method. These patterns also allow you to chain the methods in a similar way. But while in the Builder Pattern, the order in which the methods appear in the chain does not usually matter, with the Observable operators order matters.

A chain of Observable operators do not operate independently on the original Observable that originates the chain, but they operate in turn, each one operating on the Observable generated by the operator immediately previous in the chain.

Reference : [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that completely makes sense now that you've pointed that out!